# Joomla 1.5 How to divide joomla templet and use different page templet for different page

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I am new in joomla and I am going to develop a web site with joomla 1.5.
For the site I have a html css template. Now I want to convert this into joomla template with different files (Header,Footer, sidebar etc). 
Is it possible? if yes then how can i do this ?

and how can i make different page temples for my different page (such as about, Products etc)
Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting here:
http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template
[http://docs.joomla.org/JDOC:Joomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorials_Project](http://docs.joomla.org/JDOC%3aJoomla!_1.5_Template_Tutorials_Project)

I would also recommend visiting http://demo.yootheme.com or http://demo.rockettheme.com and finding one of their free templates (both have one or two, I believe) to download. That way you can analyze how a professional template is built and organized and apply it to your own project.

Your last question: To make different templates to apply to different pages. The simplest way is to follow the directions (above) to make/modify/install a second template. Then use the Joomla template manager and specify which pages apply to which template.

Comment: You're welcome! If the answer is a correct one, please remember to check the "answered" box under the voting number.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create different files for each portion of a page but it's really not necessary in Joomla. There is only one "page" in Joomla, the index.php file. The entire website is built using that file. You can control the different parts - called positions in Joomla - of the website through 3 different methods

1. using conditional statements that determine whether they need to display at all
2. using modules to place content in the various positions
3. using CSS to control the display of each module

While it is technically possible to use multiple template in Joomla, it is almost always unnecessary. In the menu items used to create the pages in Joomla, you can specify a parameter called the page class suffix. You can insert this in to the body tag of your template giving you complete control of each page in the website through CSS rather than coding another template. Use this code to add the page class suffix to your body tag -

```
<?php
   $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
   $active = $menu->getActive();
   $pageclass = "";
   if (is_object( $active )) :
     $params = new JParameter( $active->params );
     $pageclass = $params->get( 'pageclass_sfx' );
   endif; 
?>
    <body id="<?php echo $pageclass ? $pageclass : 'default'; ?>">
```

This is compatible with all the big frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show different header footer and sidebar on each pages. It can be easily possible in joomla. You have to simple create custom module in joomla and you control the display option of this module from the joomla administrator.